# Impact of On-Demand mode on Audit table data for Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am working on Amazon DynamoDB audit table.

The read/write mode was set to "Provisioning". Now, the mode is changed to "On-Demand". I have an "Audit Table" (which captures the audit information like date and time of operation, user details, etc) associated with DynamoDB. 
My questions on this are:

1) How is it impacting the data that gets created in the "Audit Table"?

2) Will the data be deleted automatically on timely bases?

3) If not, what is the maximum limit of data that a table (audit table in this case) can persist?

Please let me know if you need any more information from my side.

Waiting for your answers on my questions.

Thanks and regards,
Mahesh Bongale

Answer (score 1):

1. `Provisioning` just means that the table is initializing with whatever read/write capacity you set, or `OnDemand` capacity if you set it to that mode (similar to an auto-scaling mode where it will always deliver the throughput needed by your application). More info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html
2. No, absolutely not, unless you specifically add code that will delete old data OR set a specific TTL on your data. More info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html
3. There is no specific limit on the number of rows in a given table. It can be as much as you want. There are a few limits though on a few things, some can be lifted if you ask AWS, some can not: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html

Comment: Yes !! Sure Frsechet :-)

Comment: Hi Frsechet,
I had a question on point 2. If once the TTL is enabled on a table, can we modify it later? Because currently I see TTL is enabled and I only have "Manage TTL" button which is allowing me to only disable the TTL. 
So, how can I modify or update the TTL as per the new requirement?

Your response will be truly valuable.
Thank you !!!